# Vuejs - event bus (this.$root.$on) call is getting duplicated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

Actually on a Quasar application (Vuejs). When I load the component and go to another route and going back to the route with the component, my this.$root.$on listener on mounted() is getting duplicated.

***parent:***

```
async mounted() {
    await this.getUserInfos()
    this.$root.$on('validateB2C', data => {
      console.log('VALIDATE ??')
      console.log('receive', data)
    })
  }
```

If I go back to another route/going back to the route incluing the component like 5 times, I will got 5x the VALIDATE ?? log in the browser.

I don't know why, but I know that the this.$root.$emit is not the problem because I put a console log (test5) just before the emit and I got only one log :

***component that emits***

```
submit: function(e) {
      this.imageSelected = e
      console.log('test5')
      this.$root.$emit('validateB2C', {
        value: e.id,
        type: 'indexes',
        ref: this.data
      })
    }
```

I can't use this.$root.$once because I'm using multiple time the emit.

Also tried to put that on the parent component, but didn't work:

```
beforeDestroy () {
  this.$root.$off('validateB2C', null)
}
```

Comment: What about unbinding the event listener when the component is destroyed? You can do that in the destroyed lifecycle hook.

Comment: @Terry You mean on the parent (same component where the $root$on is?) 
I've tried beforeDestroy () {
  this.$root.$off('validateB2C', null)
} but it didn't work

Comment: That's because you need to pass the callback into the second argument, not `null`. The easier way is to abstract the callback into a function, so that you can reuse that reference when invoking `$on` and `$off`. You can also not provide the second argument at all: see the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-off

Comment: you are right, thanks! it works without the 2nd argument. I have no more issue! Thanks!